Question about the hadith where the prophet ﷺ said that someone prays 60 years but one of his salah will be accepted
Salam aleykium,
My question is about : The Prophet ﷺ said, “Indeed a person may pray for sixty years, yet not a single ṣalāh of his will be accepted. Perhaps he perfected the rukūʿ but not the sujūd, or he perfected the sujūd but not the rukūʿ” (Ibn Abī Shaybah).
Does this mean that this persons will enter jahannam for eternity? Or will the enter after a time jannah?

In both versions of the Musannaf I found online, this is reported as a mawquf report from Abu Hurairah, not from the Prophet.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. I don't see any connection between the hadith content and what you are implying about entering Jahannam.
